# how to explode string multiple color and group it using query in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, view, grouping

I have table `shoes_tbl` every shoes has a color sometime has multi color 
example:

with field : shoe, color

```
1. shoe1, black
2. shoe2, white
3. shoe3, red white
4. shoe4, red blue
5. shoe5, white
6. shoe6, blue
```

If I use :
`SELECT color FROM shoes_tbl GROUP BY color`

Output will be :

> black, white, red white, red blue, blue

I want to be :

> black, white, red, blue

Any idea? thanks..

Comment: I think your schema is not making proper use of database relations. You encode multiple relations ("red blue") in a single cell. Either you go forward with this schema and process the values (space-separated strings) outside the database.  Or you rewrite the schema into a many-to-many relation between `shoes_tbl` and another table `shoe_color`.

Comment: actualy i dont have master color table, if it can i want to show list color automaticaly as added in shoes_tbl. but if i can't do it in query. how can i do it in php script.. ??
thanks..

Comment: In php you have to use `explode()` function for that
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: As per my suggestion @Vedran is right, You have to change your schema because, If you go with further process on Column like Split than it will cause performance issue when you will have large amount of data.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend The problem is that You have an array stored in the field which is almost NEVER a good idea.

If you are at the development stage of your project I would suggest having this in 2 or 3 tables.

In the first one put shoes. In the second one put colors.
Than make a third table that is connected to the first 2 tables.

If 3 tables is to much for you make the second one (the one with colors)
in a way that the primary key is the shoe_id and color. Also make the coor an enum. It'll make things simpler.

You can than easily make this group by after joining the tables.

```
    CREATE TABLE Shoe (
        shoe_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name CHAR(50),
        price DOUBLE,
        PRIMARY KEY (shoe_id)
    );

CREATE TABLE Color (
    color_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name CHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (color_id)
);


CREATE TABLE shoe_color (
    shoe_id INT NOT NULL,
    color_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, color_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (shoe_id) REFERENCES Shoe(shoe_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (color_id) REFERENCES Color(color_id)
);
```

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT *
    FROM shoe_color AS sc
        INNER JOIN Shoe AS s ON  sc.shoe_id = s.shoe_id
        INNER JOIN Color AS c ON  sc.color_id = c.color_id
        GROUP BY c.name
;
```

A way around this is to create a master color table, join that table with the
shoe table and having a condition where you chech if the color from the master is contained in your array. 
This is much more complicated and slow in the long run. If you're making a website performance will suffer for these searches.

Comment: Something wrong with shoe_color TABLE SCHEMA
`PRIMARY KEY (id, color_id),`
1Key column 'id' doesn't exist in table1

Comment: It should be like:

`CREATE TABLE shoe_color (
    shoe_id INT NOT NULL,
    color_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (shoe_id, color_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (shoe_id) REFERENCES Shoe(shoe_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (color_id) REFERENCES Color(color_id)
);`

Comment: Can You please upvote the answer if you think it's good. I can't comment on quertions yet and it's killing me at the moment. thanks

Comment: wait.. so the only way is just make color table.. T_T, actually i don't wont it. because there are so many color of skin (shoes skin)..
I think you are right. I just want the shortcut (easy way).. 
So.. I'm gonna rebuild my table.. 
OR if there is way as i wont.. i just want to show the color list..

Comment: The problem of too many colors will still stay the same in either case. If you have it stored in some format (txt or a database) you can parse it or transfer it. If not give that job to the site admin. Just add that functionality to your CMS